# Make listofalgorithms (algorithm2e) inside a section instead of chapter

Tags: sectioning, algorithms, algorithm2e

I'm writing my thesis and I have a few algorithms (using algorithm2e) that
I want to list in my appendix, but I don't want to start a new page.
Also my listoffigures currently creates a section, not a chapter, same for my
bibliography.

Therefore I want to do the same for listofalgorithms, but I can't change it
correctly.
This is how the figure list is changed:

```
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \@cfttocstart
  \par
  \begingroup
    \parindent\z@ \parskip\cftparskip
    \section{\listfigurename}
    \@starttoc{lof}%
  \endgroup
  \@cfttocfinish%
}%
```

I have tried not changing it from chapter to section, but change the layout of
the chapter to section, but I can't get it perfectly, because I can't change
the skip distance after the heading.

This is what almost looks right:

```
\renewcommand\listalgorithmcfname{\thesection\hspace{3mm}List of Algorithms}
\begingroup
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax  % book
    \let\clearpage\relax        % report
    \titleformat{\chapter} [hang] {\Large\bfseries\sffamily} {\thesection} {1em} {}
    \listofalgorithms
\endgroup
```

I tried suggestions of similar threads, but they use other algorithm packages,
so I think the algorithm2e handles things in some different manner.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: @Werner: I can't tell you why, but it's not working. Maybe it isn't in fact using a chapter, I'm not sure. It starts on a new page and the indent is the same as chapter headers.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\listofalgorithms
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found no solution online, so I opened `algorithm2e.sty` and dug in.
There is actually an undocumented feature to do just that.

I just intended to <kbd>C-s</kbd>'d for "chapter" in the whole file until I found something interesting, and I did:

```
\ifx\l@chapter\undefined\let\algocf@seclistalgo=\section\else\let\algocf@seclistalgo=\chapter\fi
% /!\ this is not part of the solution, it just explains how I found it.
```

So this means that writing

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@chapter=\undefined
\makeatother
```

before calling `\usepackage[…]{algorithm2e}` will nicely do the trick :).

Another solution is to directly call `\@starttoc`, knowing that the list of algorithms is toc `loa`:

```
\section*{List of Algorithms} % or whatever is preferred
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{loa}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to let `\chapter` be equivalent to `\section`:

```
\begingroup
\let\chapter\section% Make \chapter equivalent to \section
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup
```

The `\chapter` update is temporary until `\listofalgorithms` is complete.